# Angularjs Dropdown won't hold value after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been working on this way too long trying to figure it out.

```
 <select class="form-control"  
                        ng-model="question.sel"  
                        ng-change="updateDropDownQuestion(question,question.sel)">
                        <option ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" ng-disabled="answer.notAnOption"  value="{{answer.acode}}">{{answer.name}}</option>
                        <option style="display:none" value="NONE">NONE</option>
                      </select>
```

Then in my js file:

```
$scope.updateDropDownQuestion = function(question, answer) {
    reset(question.code)

    $scope.formData["SOLE/SELECTED_QUESTION"] = question.code
    $scope.formData["SOLE/SELECTED_ANSWER"] = answer

    $scope.formData[question.code+"/"+answer] = true

    var questions = $scope.product.questions
    for(i=0; i <questions.length;i++){          
        if(questions[i].code == question.code){
            questions[i].sel = answer
            break;
        }
    }

    $scope.refresh()
};
```

the $scope.refresh() is where it changes back. This renders the screen.

no matter what I do it seems to render the previous state and not the current state of the drop down. This is because I am repainting the screen after the drop down changes.

It seems as though the when the screen repaints it is taking the original value first.

Any thoughts on how I can get the value to "stick" once set?
Do I need to fire some event afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Angular official site: 
Note: ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects. You might find this helpful to set the default values of your drop down. See an example below.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    { label: 'one', value: 1 },
    { label: 'two', value: 2 }
  ];
    
  // Although this object has the same properties as the one in $scope.options,
  // Angular considers them different because it compares based on reference
  $scope.incorrectlySelected = { label: 'two', value: 2 };
    
  // Here we are referencing the same object, so Angular inits the select box correctly
  $scope.correctlySelected = $scope.options[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div>
            <h2>Incorrect</h2>
            <p>We might expect the select box to be initialized to "two," but it isn't because these are two different objects.</p>
            <select ng-model="incorrectlySelected"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>

            The value selected is {{ incorrectlySelected.value }}.
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Correct</h2>
            <p>Here we are referencing the same object in <code>$scope.correctlySelected</code> as in <code>$scope.options</code>, so the select box is initialized correctly.</p>
            <select ng-model="correctlySelected"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>

            The value selected is {{ correctlySelected.value }}.
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was just working with simple strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-options` to render option elements.

Something along these lines:

```
<select class="form-control"  
                    ng-model="question.sel"  
                    ng-change="updateDropDownQuestion(question,question.sel)"
                    ng-options="answer.acode as answer.name in question.answers">
</select>
```

It also depends on what `updateDropDownQuestion` is doing, can you provide that?

Comment: I tried that syntax already. Didn't fare any better. the updateDropDownQuestion does indeed "reset" the drop down.

Comment: can you provide the code for that as an edit to your question?